# Preprocessor data retrieval MACRO

Tags: c, pointers, macros, c-preprocessor

Given the following structure:

```
struct nmslist_elem_s {
    nmptr data;
    struct nmslist_elem_s *next;
};
typedef struct nmslist_elem_s nmslist_elem;
```

Where:

```
typedef void* nmptr;
```

Is it possible to write a MACRO that retrieves the data from the element and cast it to the right type:

`MACRO(type, element)` that expands to `*((type*)element->data)`.
For example for int, I would need something like this: `*((int*)(element->data))` .

Later edit:
Yes they work, I was 'eating' some "(" and ")".
This works:

```
#define NMSLIST_DATA(type,elem) (*((type*)((elem)->data)))
#define NMSLIST_DATA_REF(type,elem) ((type*)((elem)->data))
```

Comment: What's wrong with `#define GET_DATA(type, element) *((type*)element->data)`? Am I missing something?

Comment: @sbi parentheses around `element`?

Comment: @Pete: Ah, yeah. (I'm a C++ programmer...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define RETRIEVE(type, element) *((type*)((element)->data))

RETRIEVE(int, nmptr)
// expands to
*((int*)((nmptr)->data))
```

(untested, but it should work)